# Kubernetes weirdness: cannot visit localhost, but can use curl

Tags: python, kubernetes

I am following this tutorial: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/23/get-started-with-kubernetes-using-python/ on mac osx

I have completed all of the steps

```
hello-python-6c7b478cf5-hxfvb   1/1     Running   0          114s
hello-python-6c7b478cf5-rczp9   1/1     Running   0          114s
hello-python-6c7b478cf5-snww5   1/1     Running   0          114s
hello-python-6c7b478cf5-wr8gf   1/1     Running   0          114s
```

I cannot visit localhost:6000 on my browser. I get an error:

```
The web page at http://localhost:6000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

But I can curl:

```
app git:(master) ✗  curl localhost:6000
Hello from Python!%
```

- Why is this happening?
- How to fix it?

Comment: Check if they're both resolving to the same IP address? Another random thing to try is open 127.0.0.1:6000 and see if that works in the browser

Comment: Hey try running py main.py with @app.run(debug=True) and see what domain it specifies, and then recheck with dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this demo application on minikube then minikube doesn't supports LB external IP. You can check pending status with this command : `kubectl get svc -o wide`.

Resolution :
The LoadBalancer service get a node port assigned too so you can access services via:
`$ minikube service my-loadbalancer-service-name` to open browser or add --url flag to output service URL to terminal. You should see something like:
`$ minikube service hello-python-service --url`
this command will give url output .