# Docker Desktop: expose service not showing any valid EXTERNAL-IP

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I'm new to Kubernetes. I am facing the following issue.

I created a deployment using this command.

```
$ kubectl run simple-deployment-14 --image cooldocker19/manas-simple-flask:v1.0 --port=5000
```

To expose it as a service, I used this.

```
kubectl expose deployment simple-deployment-14 --port 5000 --type=LoadBalancer --name=simple-service
```

In the above command, when I use type=`LoadBalancer`, then I see the EXTERNAL-IP is `<pending>`and with type=`NodePort`, then the EXTERNAL-IP is `none`

Here is the details of the service.

```
$ kubectl describe service simple-service-14

Name:                     simple-service-14
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=simple-deployment-14
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=simple-deployment-14
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.101.XXX.XXX
LoadBalancer Ingress:     localhost
Port:                     <unset>  5000/TCP
TargetPort:               5000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31754/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.X.XXX:5000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

I was expecting to see a working endpoint on browser, but it doesn't show anything.

Reference endpoint: `http://localhost:5000/test`

What am I missing here ?

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't show anything`? Do you have any errors? Have you tried to reach your service at  `localhost:31754`

Answer (score -1):

Already answered here check if it is helpful.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64812253/kubernetes-weirdness-cannot-visit-localhost-but-can-use-curl/64816496#64816496
```

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate, if you think it is; or leave a complete answer here that doesn't depend on following the link.

Comment: @Shashi Kumar, I am not using minikube. If you know how to fix the above issue for "docker desktop" then please share your answer.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am new to this platform so i am unaware about some feature and Manas docker desktop supports only minikube , Try this command : minikube service simple-service --url

Comment: @ShashiKumar, I am using "Docker on Mac with Kubernetes", not minikube.
Ref: https://codefresh.io/kubernetes-tutorial/local-kubernetes-mac-minikube-vs-docker-desktop/